# Trying to overwrite subset of pandas dataframe but get empty values

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataset, `df` with some empty values in second column `col2`.

so I create a new table with same column names and the lenght is equal to number of missings in `col2` for `df`. I call the new dataframe `df2`.

```
    df[df['col2'].isna()] = df2
```

But this will return `nan` for the entire rows where `col2` was missing. which means that `df[df['col1'].isna()]` is now missins everywhere and not only in `col2`.
**Why is that and how Can I fix that?**

Comment: This is probaly due to index alignment. You should add a little sample for both, `df` and `df2`, that replicates your problem.

Comment: The values you're assigning need to be the same shape as the thing you're assigning to. Maybe you could try: df[df['col2'].isna()] = df2[df['col2'].isna()] ?

Comment: Since you have the right dimensions you could try `… = df2.values`.

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). How do you get the replacement values in the first place?

Comment: Also, a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that by `df2` you really meant a `Series`, so renaming as `s`:

```py
df.loc[df['col2'].isna(), 'col2'] = s.values
```

**Example**

```py
nan = float('nan')
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,2,3], 'col2': [nan, 0, nan]})
s = pd.Series([10, 11])

df.loc[df['col2'].isna(), 'col2'] = s.values

>>> df
   col1  col2
0     1  10.0
1     2   0.0
2     3  11.0
```

**Note**

I don't like this, because it is relying on knowing that the number of NaNs in `df` is the same length as `s`. It would be better to know **how** you create the missing values. With that information, we could probably propose a better and more robust solution.